Could dragons "fold" their legs while flying?
If dragons had four legs plus two wings, their legs would obviously get in the way while flying. Many insects deal with this problem by "folding" their legs. However insects have a vastly different leg structure than dragons and are much smaller. Would it be possible for dragons to fold up their legs while flying? Would they weigh too much? How would they ensure they stay folded?

why would theire legs get in the way, that is going to depend a lot on anatomy.

What is the meaning of  dragons "folding" their legs? What is the difference between dragons "folding" their legs and just about all perching birds flexing them in flight, like for this raven for example? (As opposed to non-perching birds which extend them, like this stork.) In short, asking a question about anatomy works better when using correct terminology.

Iguana going streamlined when swimming under water.

Why shouldn't it be possible?
Many quadrupeds fold their legs already, just look at a cat

now add wings and let it fly.
This is how a four legged dragon might look like (as depicted in Gragyriss, captor of princesses)

Their weight would depend on their structure, which would be adapted to allow flight.

not just quadrapeds flying animals like birds fold their legs.
